# How to get a form processing event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as simple as like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#somebutton').click(function(){
           $('#someformid').submit();
           return false;
    });

});
```

During this form submit ,normally the page will wait for 1 or 2 sec for the load ,in this mean time user can click the 'somebutton' again and the form will submit again.My question is how do i lock the browser or disable form submit if a form submit process is going on ?

P.S somebutton is an image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [.one](http://api.jquery.com/one/), which make the handler execute at most once.

```
   $('#somebutton').one('click', function(){
       $('#someformid').submit();
       return false;
   });
```

Comment: Will one recognize all the events ? for eg `click` ,`change`

Comment: @ubercooluk Oh, my code missed, you have to assign the event type.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply disable the button from clicking while processing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#somebutton').click(function(){
           $('#someformid').submit();
           $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

});
```

or you can use `e.preventDefault();`

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
       $('#somebutton').click(function(){
               $('#someformid').submit();
               e.preventDefault();
        });

    });
```

Comment: @ubercooluk it's quite nice to mention this stuff in the question

Answer (score 1):

Add attr disabled to your button

**EDIT :** unbind the click event on click.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#somebutton').click(function(){
        $(this).unbind('click');
        $('#someformid').submit();
        return false;     
});  
});
```